# Interpreting Java crash files

Tags: java, debugging, swing, crash

I have a Swing application that is heavy customised with a lot of custom painting mainly on the panels and button to add gradients and round borders.

The application infrequently crashes with exactly the same error and i get **hs_err_pid[0000].log**

Snippet:

```
Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x032ff400 JavaThread "Thread-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3452, stack(0x04660000,0x046b0000)]
  0x02b1c400 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3524, stack(0x04850000,0x048a0000)]
  0x03198800 JavaThread "Poller Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=2444, stack(0x04610000,0x04660000)]
  0x032d3c00 JavaThread "ClientAPI::HttpConnection::InputStreamByteReader" [_thread_blocked, id=3672, stack(0x04ad0000,0x04b20000)]
  0x03288400 JavaThread "ClientAPI::HttpConnection" [_thread_blocked, id=4564, stack(0x04a30000,0x04a80000)]
  0x0329f400 JavaThread "ClientAPI::HttpPostConnection" [_thread_blocked, id=412, stack(0x049e0000,0x04a30000)]
  0x02a90400 JavaThread "MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3500, stack(0x048a0000,0x048f0000)]
  0x003a9400 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=132, stack(0x008c0000,0x00910000)]
  0x03e56800 JavaThread "Thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=2912, stack(0x04700000,0x04750000)]
  0x03e1d800 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5728, stack(0x03da0000,0x03df0000)]
  0x031abc00 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=2788, stack(0x036c0000,0x03710000)]
  0x0314ec00 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=2468, stack(0x034a0000,0x034f0000)]
=>0x02fbe400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=5836, stack(0x03450000,0x034a0000)]
  0x02a74400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3044, stack(0x02d20000,0x02d70000)]
  0x02a6e400 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3248, stack(0x02cd0000,0x02d20000)]
  0x02a6cc00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=548, stack(0x02c80000,0x02cd0000)]
  0x02a6b800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2792, stack(0x02c30000,0x02c80000)]
  0x02a63000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1504, stack(0x02be0000,0x02c30000)]
  0x02a61c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3124, stack(0x02b90000,0x02be0000)]
```

Is there a way of interpreting this file to determine what could be wrong in my application?

**Edit,** added more details

From the answered so far, this [article](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/02/19/crash-course-jvm-crash-analysis) and the snipper below, i think the setting of cursors is causing these issues.

```
Stack: [0x03450000,0x034a0000],  sp=0x0349f860,  free space=318k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0xd2db8]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.awt.Cursor.finalizeImpl(J)V+0
j  java.awt.Cursor.access$000(J)V+1
j  java.awt.Cursor$CursorDisposer.dispose()V+13
j  sun.java2d.Disposer.run()V+26
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Comment: there ought to be some sort of exception cause along with a stacktrace in the dump file - do you have those as well?

Comment: So what are you doing with cursors?

Comment: I have a panel on which i set the normal cursor and the busy cursor when i'm waiting for an action on the server. I recursively iterate through all components setting the cursor depending on the state. I have made sure i don't instantiate them myself by calling **Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR)**

Comment: @n002213f - you don't need to iterate through all components and set the cursor. Setting the cursor on a container (e.g., a JFrame) will cause all contained components to use that cursor also.

Comment: @Nemi - noted, i have made the change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/02/19/crash-course-jvm-crash-analysis) is a very good guide to interpreting `hs_err` log files, particularly on Windows. It's quite an involved process, unfortunately, but should ultimately guide you to the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that link is broken now.

Answer (score 1):

Note that unless you use JNI, nothing your application does, no matter, how wrong, should result in a crash of the JVM. I'd try running it on different JVMs and machines to rule out JVM bugs and hardware problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Sun JRE that diagnostics should give a link to the appropriate bug report page. http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

It's worth ensuring that you have an up to date JRE (6u15/6u16) and up to date graphics card drivers.

Comment: while thats good, i want to make sure i have established the cause of the crash and maybe have a workaround instead of asking users to get the current JRE

Comment: If they don't have 6u15, they will have known security vulnerabilities (for untrusted code at the least). You might want to push them along.

Comment: In that context i will push for an upgrade of JRE, at least we were signing the application.