# Simple java class to download the file

Tags: java, download, runtime-error, urlconnection

I am trying to download a file using simple java class using the following code:

```
public class Download {  

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  

        Download d = new Download();  
        d.URLSetUp("http://www.sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html");  
     }  

    public String URLSetUp(String urlProp) throws Exception {  

        StringBuffer tempData = new StringBuffer();  
        String contentXML = "";  
        String line = "";  
        URL url1;  
         try {  
            url1 = new URL(urlProp);  

            URLConnection conn = url1.openConnection();  

            conn.setDoOutput(true);  
             OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn
                .getOutputStream());  

             BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
                .getInputStream()));  
              while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {  
                 tempData.append(line);  
             }  
             contentXML = tempData.toString();  

            wr.close();  
            rd.close();  

         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {  

             e.printStackTrace();  
         } catch (IOException e) {  

             e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
         if (contentXML != null) {  
             return contentXML;  
        } else {  

             System.out.println("Error");  
         }  
         return null;  

     }  
}
```

Its giving me following error:

```
#  
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:  
#  
#  Internal Error (434C41535326494C453041525345520E4350500B65), pid=5156, tid=4296  
#  
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.6.0_03-b05 mixed mode)  
# An error report file with more information is saved as hs_err_pid5156.log  
#  
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:  
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp  
#
```

Please let me know if any of you have got any soultion.

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: Removed the 'eclipse' tag, as per [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128954/179533)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've probably determined, that's your virtual machine crashing. Nothing you do normally within Java should trigger this, and consequently I would start by upgrading your JVM. 1.6.0_**03** is quite old.

[This page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) details the Java 7 downloads, and the earlier Java 6 JDKs too. As you can see they're up to minor version 31 so you're relatively out-of-date.

If you want to debug this further, note the above error report file and check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1559940/12960).

Answer (score 1):

The source file is correct, I try it and it works.

Only one error, but it is not related to your problem. You are using `readLine()` method. When you get the line and you append it to `tempData` you lose the line termination chars, so remember to fix this, or you alter the file.