# Java class to downlaod file

Tags: java, url, connection, download, connectexception

I am trying to download a file using simple java class using the following code:

[Simple java class to download the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104655/simple-java-class-to-download-the-file)

Its giving me following error for my url:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect  
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)  
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)  
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)  
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)  
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)  
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)  
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)  
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)  
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)  
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)  
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)  
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)  
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)  
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)  
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)  
at Download.URLSetUp(Download.java:32)  
at Download.main(Download.java:16)
```

Please let me know if any of you have got any soultion.

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: What is the code of `line:32` of your class?? Your exception generates from this line

Comment: OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn
     .getOutputStream());  this s the Line: 32

Comment: I had compile and run your code successfully without any error or exception. I am on NetBeans 7.1 with JDK 7...just remeber one thing that your `urlProp` must be a string starting with `http://www.`

Comment: one thing more, check your firewall settings. It may be happen that either eclipse or java is blocked by your firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java 1.5 you can also pass a java.net.Proxy instance to the openConnection() method:

```
//Proxy instance, proxy ip = 192.168.0.1 with port 8080  

Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.1", 8080));
URL url = new URL("http://www.sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html");
HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
uc.connect ();

OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(uc
              .getOutputStream());  

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc
                .getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have connection with that URL.

Have you tried that URL from web browser?

Maybe there is proxy between you and that URL?

Comment: through browser i am able to access it

Comment: i tried to access d.URLSetUp("http://www.sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html"); even this url, which works fine in browser but getting Unknownhost and connection refused: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.sheldonbrown.com
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

If your browser needs a proxy to access this URL, your application will require a proxy, too.

To setup a proxy for the `URLConnection` have a look at [this page](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0085.html)

It might be simple, as running your application with the following parameters

`java -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxyserver.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 Download`